# Append new Item to a list in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a very simple form which gets `name` and `age` from user and add this to a list.

You can check that on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rez3qjxL/97/).

Here is HTML :

```
<div id="app">
<ul>
  <li v-for="user in users">{{ user.name +' '+ user.age }}</li>
</ul>
<hr>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="addNewUser">
    <input v-model="user.name" />
    <input v-model="user.age" />
    <button type="submit">Add User</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Here is Vue code:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
    users: [{name:"Mack", age:20}],
    user: {name:"", age:0}
   },
   methods: {
     addNewUser() {
        this.users.push(this.user);
     }
   }
});
```

**The Problem**

The problem is where I trying to add more than one user to the list. As you can see, when I type new value for the new user, previous values of recently added users change too!

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you push `this.user` to the array you're pushing the reference to that data.  Instead, create a new object using the data from the `user` object:

```
this.users.push({ name: this.user.name, age: this.user.age })
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be creating a new object which should be decoupled from the data.

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
    users: [{name:"Mack", age:20}],
    user: {name:"", age:0}
   },
   methods: {
     addNewUser() {
        let newUser = {
           name: this.user.name,
           age: this.user.age
        };

        this.users.push(newUser);
     }
   }
});
```

One more thing I'd suggest; I see that you are interpolating the value of the name and age by writing `{{ user.name +' '+ user.age }}` while instead you could convert that into a computed property and make it more reusable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `lodash`, try this.

```
this.users.push(_.cloneDeep(this.user))
```